# Dataframe column using for loop to replace value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a column that is either 0 or negative values. What I need to do is convert this column to absolute values, then replace any value less than 1.0, with 1.0. Then I used the min/max function to validate the dataframe with no success. I also tried just dropping any values less than 1, use the same min/max function to validate and it works. I have no idea why my for loop does not work as expected.

```
    df['snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS'] = abs(df['snapshotMp60sLowTicks'])

for x in df.index:
    if df.loc[x,'snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS'] < 1.0:
        df.replace(x,value=1.0,inplace=True)
      

#Min Max
print("snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS (Max):",max(df['snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS']))
print("snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS (Min):",min(df['snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS']))
```

The output of the above is this:

```
snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS (Max): 160.41666666666788
snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS (Min): 0.0
24750    0.911550
21135    3.005806
5639     2.658351
31381    1.687291
41110    1.022213
19468    4.759551
18290    3.821735
20325    0.785548
32971    5.044653
30072    4.082064
Name: snapshotMp60sLowTicksABS, dtype: float64

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `df['column'] = df['column'].abs().clip(lower=1.0)`?

Comment: Hey Quang Hoang- that worked well! Thank you for that. How would you say replace values lower or higher than 1.0 with something else in that syntax?